# How can I customize a wordpress multi-site install and add my own HTML5 code?

Tags: wordpress, html, customization

So this is my goal and I'm hoping that wordpress multi-site will do it for me.

Basically they sign up, get their own subdomain, get a stripped down wordpress multisite blog with just a form so they can upload audio files and photos. I also want them to be able to upload a custom header file if they choose.

When other users see their site they will see a music player, header, some photos, and the information entered into the form as descriptions for music and photos.

Each user upon sign in will have their ow xml file and directory.

I want the music player to use a custom music player I have written that will populate itself from the users xml file and a mysql db.

In the future id like to be able to pull random audio and photos from all users and make a completely seperate playlist of songs and what not.

I don't want to use plugins, i'd prefer to code as much of it myself as possible while also coding as little of it as possible, if that makes any sense?

Is a stripped down wordpress multi-site the best way to do this? Or should I simply code the whole thing myself in Html 5?

Also, and tutorials, resources, code, whatever that's provided will be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

> get a stripped down wordpress multisite blog with just a form so they can upload audio files and photos. I also want them to be able to upload a custom header file if they choose.

This just involves removing a bunch of the menu items. Look at the "Menus" plugin in the repo.

> When other users see their site they will see a music player, header, some photos, and the information entered into the form as descriptions for music and photos.

That'd be just a theme.